# Get date of next thursday (including today if we are thursday)

Tags: php, date

I need to get the date of the next thursday.
So far, I'm using `strtotime('next thursday');` to got it. It worked well until I realise it gives me the date of thursday next week if we are thursday today...

What would be the best way to get the next thursday including today's date in calculation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if((int) date('N') === 4) {
    return date('Y-m-d'); // today is thursday
}
else {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next thursday'));
}
```

Comment: I though about this solution. I was hoping I could find something "shorter".

Comment: Should be `=== 5`.

Comment: Thursday is the fourth day of the week.

Comment: Sunday = 0 - Monday = 1 - Tuesday = 2 - Wednesday = 3 - Thursday = 4 - Friday = 5 - Saturday = 6

Comment: @krasipenkov Here's something shorter: `return (int) date('N') === 4 ? date('Y-m-d') : date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next thursday'));`. I think Pierrick's answer is quite good.

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php:
N ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0) 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

Comment: When you use 'w' option than they are Sunday = 0 - Monday = 1 - Tuesday = 2 - Wednesday = 3 - Thursday = 4 - Friday = 5 - Saturday = 6

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for the short solution. When you use "N", days are : Monday = 1 - Tuesday = 2 - Wednesday = 3 - Thursday = 4 - Friday = 5 - Saturday = 6 - Sunday = 7

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
if( date( 'N' ) == 4 )
{
    echo date( 'd-m-Y' );
}
echo date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( 'next thursday' ) );
```